# creating a DataFrame in reactivity loop

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, plotly, shiny-reactivity

I am using shiny to create a reactive graph. Everything works fine. Furthermore, I want to render a table with the same filtered data as the graph is using.

Before I filtered via `tidyverse` (%>%filter) within the renderPlot function. Wanting to use the same filters as before to plot the table, I need to save the filtered db to a df before I render plots.

Do you know how this can be achieved? I tried to do it like this

```
dataInput <- reactive({
   data_angepasst  %>%
     filter(if (input$zeitpunkt.length() != 0) DOP %in% input$zeitpunkt) %>%
     filter(if (input$projekt.length() != 0) Projektname %in% input$projekt)
 })
```

After that, I am trying to render a datable with dataInput as input.

I am wondering why this does not work the way I want it to do.

Comment: Do you call it ``dataInput()` like this ? (note parenthesis)

Comment: I don't get what you are talking about. :/ I try to use dataInput as output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
   
    datatable(dataInput, filter = 'top', options = list(pageLength = 8, scrollX = TRUE))
    
  })

Comment: It would easier if you would post a reproducible example. And it should be.. `datatable(dataInput(),...`

Comment: Yes, I talked about what @MLavoie told you, you forget the parenthesis with `dataInput`

Comment: i got it! Thank to both of you. This trick did the magic :)